# Repulsive charges in bounded potential

Tags: electrostatics, potential-energy, equilibrium

I'm interested in Centroidal Voronoi tessellation especially on disk.
When I got these diagrams, I thought *I saw* something like this
[image]
Looks like a relaxed distribution of identical charges inside the repulsive circle.
So raised the following questions:

- I can’t remember which article or textbook saw it, I really hope for advice!
- For the same number of seeds (generators) there are different stable CVTs (as above, for $N = 10$ there are 3 such)
  If the charges relax in a bounded potential, do we get different configurations for different initial conditions?
- Is this not contrary to Earnshaw's theorem?
- Stable CVTs are local minimizers of some energy-like function:
  $$\mathscr{E(\mathbf{S})} = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{V_i} \lVert \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{s_i} \rVert^2 \,d\sigma$$
  (where $\mathbf{S}$ are seeds and ${V_i}$ - corresponding Voronoi cells)
  while charge distribution minimises potential energy.
  Is it possible to use some form of potential (non-coulomb?) to find some correspondence?